# Trigger After update doesn't show custom exception message

Tags: apex, trigger, exception

I created a trigger  that throws an exception when the Order do not have the required attachment types. I would like the message **'Required document types were not found'** to be displayed to the user.
But what is showing is the default message(see in the image):

> There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help.

I tried using `trigger.addError()`, but as the method `verifyFileAttachmentType` only takes `Set<String>`, I don't think it would work. What should I do to solve it?

P.S: I'm using `Set<String>` instead of `Set<Id>` because `AuxiliarMethods.sizeOfContentVersionTypes` calls an Integration Procedure (Vlocity).
[image]

VerifyAttachmentType.cls

```
public class VerifyAttachmentType {

    public class VerifyAttachmentTypeException extends Exception{}

 
    public static void verifyFileAttachmentType(Set<String> linkedEntityIds){
        
        for(String linkedEntityId : linkedEntityIds){
            
            Map<String, Object> mapOutput = AuxiliarMethods.sizeOfContentVersionTypes(linkedEntityId);
            Integer sizeOfDocType1 = Integer.valueOf(mapOutput.get('DocType1'));
            Integer sizeOfDocType2 = Integer.valueOf(mapOutput.get('DocType2'));
            Integer sizeOfDocType3  = Integer.valueOf(mapOutput.get('DocType3'));
            
            if( !(sizeOfDocType1 > 0 && sizeOfDocType2 > 0 && sizeOfDocType3 > 0) ){
                throw new VerifyFileAttachmentTypeException('Required document types were not found');
            }
        } 
    }}
```

Trigger

```
trigger OrderTrigger on Order (after update){
      
            Set<String> setOrderId = new Set<String>();

            for(Order ord : Trigger.new){
                   setOrderId.add(ord.Id);
            }
            
            if (setOrderId.size() > 0) {
                VerifyAttachmentType.verifyFileAttachmentType(setOrderId);
            }
    }
```

Comment: do you have the freedom to rewrite `VerifyAttachmentType`, if yes - I can offer a solution

Answer (score 0):

I've found it necessary to call `setMessage` to get the text output at the client-side:

```
String m = 'Required document types were not found';
Exception e = new VerifyFileAttachmentTypeException(m);
e.setMessage(m);
throw e;
```

Comment: Thanks! But it's working like the original code... :(

Comment: Hi @Ana, Woops, didn't look carefully enough; presumably the code that causes the trigger to run is mapping everything explicitly or implicitly to e.g. a `DmlException`. Are you using custom Apex code for that or something generic like LDS?

Comment: It's only Apex code

Comment: ... and @Ana the exception thrown to the client side needs to be or extend `AuraHandledException`.